# How does a Windows program know if I'm printing to PDF?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, print-to-pdf, cutepdf

I use a program that won't let me print to PDF, only directly to a printer. If I try to print to PDF using CutePDF for example, it prints out a blank page that says the feature is not supported. However, I need to print to PDF so I can transfer the document to another computer that has a printer connected to it.

How does the program know if I'm printing to a PDF or directly to a printer? Is there a way to spoof this so I'm allowed to print to PDF? What is technically different between the two?

Comment: Perhaps its CutePDF that is not supporting something. Try another free PDF printer. I recommend the MyPDF Converter. Just be careful to decline all the "Install ??? Hot Bar" requests that come with it during the installation, it can ruin your computer.

Comment: If CutePDF can handle PostScript input, you can install a dummy PostScript printer on your computer, select it as the active printer, tell the program to print but tell it to put the output into a file, then lastly tell CutePDF to convert the output file into a PDF.

Comment: A similar idea would be to print to the Microsoft XPS Document Writer and then afterwards go into the XPS viewer and print to the CutePDF virtual printer from there.

Comment: I've now tried all of these ideas to no avail. I tried MyPDF...it knows. It knows when I'm using XPS Document Writer. It even knows when I set up a fake PostScript printer. How is this possible?

Comment: It seems martineau has provided the best solution.

Comment: Have you tried installing a dummy printer queue (of the same type as the final destination printer) and using the "print to file" function?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx you can see one of the fields that can be queried is the name of the printer. Possibly the program looks for a printer with the name of the popular PDF printer programs.

Is it possible to rename your PDF printer?